Thermostat Cable for Outdoor HVAC unit
I have a signal cable (thermostat cable) which runs to the AC outdoor unit and has a joint in the middle. While it currently works fine, should I move the cable around, the outdoor unit fan does not start. I want to replace the nuts at cable joint with a more reliable connector. Which one should I use?
The AC outdoor unit is: Lennox; ML14XP1-030-230A01; S/N 1920B18027.
 

@Ecnerwal Added an image of the outdoor unit label. Does that help?

Would you add a picture showing a better "overall look" at the installation? I have a hunch the thick gray cable (the "UF cable" mentioned in an answer) is not protected from physical damage as it ought to be.

If the junction is properly made and protected in a junction box there should be no need, and there's no good reason to replace the whole cable just because there's a junction in it. If the junction is presently sub-standard and not to code, merely fixing it so it is up to standard and meets code should be reliable at the same level as the connections at either end.
Now that you have edited in a picture of the incredibly awful excuse for a junction, without a junction box, probably not using weatherproof wirenuts, outside, on your thermostat wiring - um, yeah. Even low voltage should be done "in a neat and professional manner" and whether or not you technically need a junction box for code, you surely need one for making that more reliable - it provides a place to strain-relieve the cables so they don't pull on the wires in the nuts, provides some limited weather protection (but you should still be using water resistant wire nuts, which are common and available - try the irrigation supplies if you can't spot them in the electrical aisle, as they are used for irrigation control wire, among other things) and makes the connection more reliable.
The standard amateur problem with wire nuts is not twisting them tight enough. I don't know if the "lever-lock" new-fangled things are offered in a waterproof version. I do know that 3M ScotchLok IDC [Insulation Displacement Connectors] (just a happy user) are.

Image source

Image Source
They are filled with grease, and have a blade with slots that cuts through the insulation (no stripping by you required) to connect 2 or three wires that you poke into the connector before squeezing it closed on the wires. Very commonly used in telephone wiring, which is also low-voltage wiring that's not uncommonly located outdoors. That will still be better with all of them protected inside a junction box.

The picture of the splice looks more like thermostat cable.  Unknown if OP mixed the cables up.

My bad. This is not a power cable as I assumed earlier. The reason why I wanted it replaced was because there was loose connection on the wire nuts a few days ago which resulted in the Outdoor unit fan not starting, which also made me believe it was the power cable. That also means replacing it would be a lot more difficult now. So is there a better connector available other than wire nuts used in similar cases?

@Ecnerwal Thanks, just chnaged

The spliced cable (with the wire nuts) is more of a signal cable, than a power cable.  If you want to replace it, search for "thermostat eight wire cable" to find 18/8 thermostat cable.  It's standard.  You do not need to worry about meeting specifications generally.  The standard stuff can easily handle up to a hundred feet for normal applications.
Counting wire nuts, you only seem to be using five of the eight wires.  This is not uncommon.  Using the /8 for five wires allows for future expansion.  Wrapping the unused wires back around the cable is a common approach to keeping them out of the way.
Some of your pictures do show power cables.  Those will need a much larger carrying capacity.  The one label says 17 and 25 amps, but another label says 30 amps at 240 volts).  Check the circuit breaker.  The wires need to be able to support at least the amperage of the circuit breaker.  The length of the cable also matters.  If you do need to change that, post the circuit breaker size (take a picture of the panel) and the measured length of the cable.  It's better to oversize wires than undersize them.  Oversizing costs money; undersizing risks fire.

You are right. This is not a power cable as I assumed earlier. Its the thermostat cable I believe. The reason why I wanted it replaced was because there was loose connection on the wire nuts a few days ago which resulted in the Outdoor unit fan not starting, which also made me believe it was the power cable. That also means replacing it would be a lot more difficult now. So is there a better connector available other than wire nuts used in similar cases? Any specific Amp rating for a connector used in this case?

@Hil  That cable is considered low voltage so most things are allowed, compared to household(120/240v) cables that have code requirements.  It is usually cheaper cable so replacing it with new without a splice is best.  Not sure/doubt that cable is wet rated for outdoor use, so any splice is problematic anyway.

The “30A” label is obviously on a disconnect. The disconnect just has to be at least as big as the breaker. The breaker and wire do not need to be (and should not be) upsized to match the disconnect.

440.32 says air conditioning conductor size is 125% of circuit ampacity, so 17*1.25= 21.25. UF limited to 60°C. #12 only good for 20A, so minimum UF size is #10.
UF can't be used where subject to physical damage, so it likely needs to be run in Liquid tight flexible conduit. Pulling flat 10/2 UF likely would require 3/4" due to requirement to calculate fill as round cable of the largest dimension, so you might want to run THWN conductors, where 25A #12 conductors can be run in 1/2".
The wire between panel and disconnect is likely NM-B (Romex) and if it is it needs to be #10 also since it is also limited to 60°C, so #12 is only good for 20A, not 21.25A. 30A or 25A fuses at the local disconnect is OK since protected ahead by the 25A breaker.

440.32 is for a "single motor-compressor". This packaged condenser contains a hermetic motor and a fan motor so 440.35 applies instead. "The ampacity of the conductors supplying multimotor and combination-load equipment shall not be less than the minimum circuit ampacity marked on the equipment in accordanced with 440.4(B)." The 125% multiplier of 440.32 does not apply.
